# Chrome Extension browserAction not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to pass message from background page to content page, below is my code. I have tried downloading code samples from extension library, but it is not working even after that,

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        greeting: "hello"
    }, function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    });
});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test Screenshot Extension",
    "version": "1.3",
    "description": "Demonstrate screenshot functionality in the chrome.tabs api.",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon-128.png",
        "48": "icon-48.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon-128.png",
        "default_title": "Take a screen shot!"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The line **alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));** alerts"undefined"

Comment: Where are you injecting the content script?

Comment: If you check sample extension named Email this page (by Google), they aren't also injecting the content.js via manifest json.

Comment: They use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject it but you don't?

Comment: So what need to be done to make my code work? Through manifest or by using execute script?

Comment: Yes, either via manifest so that it's injected always on the specified urls or via executeScript so that it's injected for example after you click the button in which case you might not need messaging depending on what you actually do in the content script.

Comment: a great rookie mistake is not reading this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted